# Mixture of Hibernate and Raw JDBC app is locking up

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2

I took over a company's Java Web application that stands at 30k lines of code.  There are about 20 users on the system.  The application originally did raw jdbc sql queries.  I have converted some of the SQL to hibernate, but because of time and budget constraints I have not converted all of it.  My thinking was that I could do a mixture of the two db interaction methods (hibernate and raw jdbc), while I incrementally migrate the app to all hibernate.  It's using c3p0 connection pooling.  It uses two pools; one for hibernate and one for the raw jdbc queries.  There are some raw jdbc update and insert queries, but they are now all using hibernate's `session.doWork(Work work)` hook.  The db is Microsoft SQL Server '08 R2.

The problems we experience with this approach always seem to manifest themselves as the app locking up.  For the past month, I have been able to reduce the frequency of lock-ups by fixing obvious problems.  I am at a point now, where the cause is not so obvious, and my boss and I suspect that there is something fundamentally wrong in our approach or configuration that would solve this problem entirely.

One thing that is confusing to me is that if these lock-ups are db deadlocks, the thread dumps only seem to indicate that a write is blocking a read.  However, the transaction isolation level is read-committed, so why would a write block a read?

Are there any suggestions you can give?  Any suggestions for better debugging analyis?

Here are is the properties from my persistence.xml file

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="20" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="300" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
```

I'm using the default c3p0 configuration for the raw jdbc select queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you would have solved the issue by now but if not you could check this link out http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html

You can start by checking that your application doesn't have long open transactions.

Comment: I'm not certain that the problem has been solved yet, but as of last week, I think it might be.  Last week we put in newrelic app monitoring.  I found some long-running transactions and it made me think of some more to fix.  The app seems to be doing much better since then.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the more transactions and hibernate proxy objects opened by your code, and perhaps you have more logical transaction broken or not closed.

Hibernate create a proxy object upon a single record that you retrieve from database into a logical transaction. If you change this record in another transaction, or you synchronize these proxies with the their transaction or hibernate runs more refresh operations to update these proxies (if their transaction is open).

Now, my questions, to help you, are these:

- can you develop new code ? If not, I suggest to leave Hibernate.

if yes:

- I suggest to create a middle tier to manage the logical transaction between data layer and all your code.
- Use some IDE with JPA 2.0 support to create objects by database reverse engineering.